# Showing that $x \sim y$ if $x^n=y^n$ defines an equivalence relation on group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

How can we show that given a group $G$ and $x,y \in G$ that $x \sim y$ if $x^n = y^n$, for some $n > 0$, defines an equivalence relation? The only issue is transitivity, because we need to work with $x^n = y^n$ and $y^m = z^m$. I tried to use the division algorithm but that didn't seem to help. Any clues or help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider $n \cdot m$.

Comment: Am I missing something? Won't the only equivalence class be $[e]$ since $x^{|G|} = e$ for all $x \in G$? I suppose something more interesting could happen with infinite groups.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MarkSaving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$. Then there exist $n,m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x^n=y^n$ and $y^m=z^m$. Consider $x^{mn}$: we have

$$\begin{align}
x^{mn}&=(x^n)^m\\
&=(y^n)^m\\
&=(y^m)^n\\
&=(z^m)^n\\
&=z^{mn}.
\end{align}$$

Hence $x\sim z$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, @eng2math.